# How to connect to database on serverless sql pool via service principal?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, serverless, azure-synapse

I want to connect to a serverless sql pool database via service principal in synapse analytics. For a dedicated sqlpool the following connection string worked just fine:

```
"driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};server=tcp:xxxx.sql.azuresynapse.net;port=1433;database=sqlpool1;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal;"
```

I changed the server of connection string to the serverless one and replaced the database name:

```
"driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};server=tcp:xxxx-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net;port=1433;database=db_test;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal;"
```

This, however, does not work. I get the following error

```
Status 28000, Code 18456, Nachricht [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'
```

What can I do to make this connection work?

Answer (score 1):

`Error: Login failed for user` indicates that the user is invalid and typically refers to an AAD user that hasn't been made as a user on the SQL database you're attempting to connect to SQL serverless database or that the user isn't the AAD Server Admin.

Connect to the database using an Azure AD identify as a user with at least the ALTER ANY USER access in order to establish a contained database user (other than the server administrator who controls the database). then employ the Transact-SQL code as follows:

```sql
CREATE  USER [service principal name] FROM  EXTERNAL  PROVIDER
```

I also created same and now able to connect serverless SQL pool with Service principal authentication.

[image]

Connection successful:
[image]

Reference: [Setup a Microsoft Azure SQL Database Service Principal](https://querysurge.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/5068382921869-Setup-a-Microsoft-Azure-SQL-Database-Service-Principal-Versions-9-0-)